# Loader doesn't appear when routed to a page after first time in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I'm working on a project which has multiple links on first page. If a link is clicked application is routed to respective page with some delay. During that delay application shows a loader. But loader is displayed only for the first time I click on a link. It doesn't appear when I go back to first page and then click on a link loader doesn't appear.What may be the reason and how can I solve this problem?? Below is the HTML snippet:

```html
<template>
   
    <!-- MAIN MENU START -->
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
 

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default topMenu" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Remove button that appears for xs devices
                
                <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
            </div>-->
            <a class="navbar-brand nameEllipsis" id="routeTitle">${router.title}</a>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling
                .Remove this div to remove collapse features
                .change display of both ul to inline-block so that they appear inline
                .float 2nd ul to right to bring li to right and inline
                .float 1st li of 2nd ul to left so that it displays according to the format of md and lg devices
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1"> -->
                <ul  style="display:inline-block;"   class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li ><a  href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul style="float:right;display:inline-block;" id="navigatingIcons" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li style="float:left;" ><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-filter"></span></a></li>
                    <li  ><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span></a></li>
                    <li  class="loader" show.bind="router.isNavigating">
                        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        <!-- </div>-->   <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>



</template>
```

[image]
Above image when application is being routed for the first time. Also, aurelia-hide class is not present for the first time.[image]
Above image when application is routed after first time, aurelia-hide class is not removed and loader doesn't appear.
Thanks.

Comment: Delay maybe bacause of ajax call.But ajax call is being done everytime so delay is experienced everytime not for the first time only.Yes, project is in IE only. Not tried on other browsers.

Comment: tried on chrome as well.Problem still persists.